# development eclipse

Tags: android, development-environment

sir pls tell me the some sites where I can learn the basics of eclipse Juno for making apps as I have seen the developer site of eclipse already but not found great there so sir advised me some useful websites from there I can learn from basic to higher level.. pls sir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android development is done in java. just visit [Developer site of android](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and read how to develop android app. you do not need to go into details how eclipse work so far i know. there are other website available for beginners. [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/) and [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/)